# Generating a simple cross by stacking html elements

Tags: html, css, absolute

I'm trying and failing to generate a simple cross (made with `vertical` and `horizontal` components) within a parent element (`box`).

```css
.box {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.vertical {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  top: calc((100% - 80%) / 2);
  left: calc((100% - 10%) / 2);
  background-color: black;
}

.horizontal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 10%;
  top: calc((100% - 10%) / 2);
  left: calc((100% - 80%) / 2);
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="vertical"></div>
  <div class="horizontal"></div>
</div>
```

The output that I expected was a black cross centred within the blue a box. Can someone please tell me where I've gone wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: don't overcomplicate a simple task. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55281827/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif Can you control/animate the vertical and horizontal components individually?

Comment: it depends on what kind of animation you want but yes you an control each line using background-size/background-position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making the parent `.box` relative, you keep `.vertical` and `.horizontal` relative to `.box` and not the window (or other parent element with relative).

Try this:

```
.box {
 width: 50vmin;
 height: 50vmin;
 background-color: blue;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative; /* CHANGED HERE */
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.vertical {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  top: calc((100% - 80%) / 2);
  left: calc((100% - 10%) / 2);
  background-color: black;
}

.horizontal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 10%;
  top: calc((100% - 10%) / 2);
  left: calc((100% - 80%) / 2);
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="vertical"></div>
  <div class="horizontal"></div>
</div>
```